# Automatic theorem prover for proving simple theorems?

Tags: logic, axioms, automated-theorem-proving, theorem-provers

Is there a simple software that I could use to practice proving theorems in my course of mathematical logic? Basically what I need is ability to 1) define what axioms and laws I am allowed to use in proving theorem and 2) the theorem itself. What I want to see is steps how this theorem is proved. I looked at Jape. However presentation of proving steps seem to me unclear. And there is almost no documentation for that software.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you interested in propositional logic or first-order logic?

Comment: I believe first-order logic.

Comment: See http://www.metamath.org/.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I think metamath is only a verifier.

Answer (score 1):

In my course of mathematical logic we use this:
http://www.spass-prover.org/

Answer (score 1):

I like [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/) for theorem proving.  I think [OTTER](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/otter/) is better for some purposes.